# Built-in font not available in pdf2docx python

Tags: python, pdf, fonts, docx

Here is a code to convert a book from pdf to word format.

```
from pdf2docx import Converter

cv = Converter('Calculus.pdf')
cv.convert('Calculus.docx', start=0, end=None) 
cv.close()
```

It seems that my pdf has text in Arial font and it is not able to detect it... So I get this error

```
    _fitz.Font_swiginit(self, _fitz.new_Font(fontname, fontfile, fontbuffer, script, language, ordering, is_bold, is_italic, is_serif, embed))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: cannot find builtin font with name 'Arial'
```

But this font is available in my PC, in path

```
C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\ARIAL.TTF
```

Is there any way to include this font in my program so that pdf2docx is able to detect it?